# How to allow only lower case as input arguments in Bash

Tags: bash

I want to allow only lower case in my input. I've tried [a-z], [a-z^A-Z] and also [:lower:]. But it doesn't help.

All the expressions are going to else loop only if the whole string in uppercase.

Example:

If 1. Demo --- It says syntax valid
   2. demo --- It says syntax valid
   3. DEMO --- It says syntax invalid

But I need the syntax invalid even if the input is similar to example 1.

```
#!/bin/bash
client_name=$1

if [[ "$client_name" =~ [:lower:] ]]
        then
        echo " CLIENT Name Syntax is Valid"
        else
        echo -e "CLIENT Name Syntax is Invalid"  
        exit 01
fi
```

Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[:lower:] check if lowercase exist use [:upper:] instead

```
client_name="Demo"

if [[ "$client_name" =~ [[:upper:]] ]]; then
  echo "uppercase character found"
else 
  echo "all lowercase"
fi
```

Comment: Hey Christian!! Thanks, But I'm not looking for a conversion. I just need to allow only lowercase as input arguments.

Comment: [:lower:] is used to find if lowercase exist and so does [a-z]

Comment: use upper instead

 'client_name="Demo"

    if [[ "$client_name" =~ [[:upper:]] ]]; then
      echo "uppercase character found"
    else 
      echo "all lowercase"
    fi'

Comment: `[[ "$client_name" =~ ^[[:lower:]]+$ ]] && echo "only lower found"`?

Comment: @Cyrus Awesome, it works. Thanks a lot. If you explain it, it helps me

Comment: @ChristianGarcia : Your soution would accept _ab55_, although _5_ is not a lower case character.

Comment: @AhamedN: `^[[:lower:]]+$`: `^`(start of line/input), `+` (one or more of the characters or character classes to the left), `$` (end of line/input). See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

`[[:lower:]]` matches a single lower case character. Hence you are testing whether your string contains a lower case character somewhere.

What you are looking for is to find whether there is a character which is **not** a lower case character, and then issue an error. This can be done for instance with

```
if [[ $client_name =~ [^[:lower:]] ]]
then 
  echo $client_name contains at least one non-lower case character
else
  echo OK
fi
```

The `^` negates the elements of the character set in the regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Or just make them lowercased

```
$ test="ASDFasdaSDaDASDasdczXVSD"
$ echo ${test,,}
asdfasdasdadasdasdczxvsd
```